# What's the intuition behind the definition of the tangent space of $\Bbb R^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

I'm reading a book on differential forms and on page one it defines the tangent space to $\Bbb R^n$.  In what follows I've translated the statements into two dimensions for simplicity.

Let $p$ be a point of $\Bbb R^2$.  The set of vectors $q-p$, $q\in\Bbb R^3$ (that have origin an $p$) will be called the *tangent space* of $\Bbb R^2$ at $p$ and will be denoted by $\Bbb R^2_p$.  The vectors $e_1=(1,0)$, $e_2=(0,1)$ will be identified with their translates $(e_1)_p$, $(e_2)_p$ at the point $p$.

So I get that $p$ is now the origin because $p-p=(0,0)$.  But what happens to $e_1$ and $e_2$?  Suppose $p=(1,1)$.  Then $(e_1)_p=(0,1)-(1,1)=(0,-1)$ right?  But that points down.  Shouldn't $e_1$ translate to something that points in the same direction as $e_1$?  My intuition tells me $(e_1)_p$ should point to $(1,2)$ which is the translation of $e_1$ to start at $(1,1)$.

So obviously my intuition is whack on this.  What am I missing here and what's the right way to think about this?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: What have origin at $p$ in your definition? $q-p$, or $q$?

Answer (score 0):

The translate $(e_1)_p$ is the unique vector satisfying $(e_1)_p - p = e_1$, so $(e_1)_p = p+e_1$. And, of course, similarly for $e_2$.

In your example $p = (1, 1)$, $(e_1)_p = (1,1)+(1, 0) = (2, 1)$ and $(e_2)_p = (1, 2)$.